# ImageCell not displaying image loaded from a URI

Tags: c#, xamarin

I am coding an app that pulls JSON data from FLickr and displays an list of image cells. The app gives no errors and allows a search to be entered and pulls the data. The title data displays without issue but the image remains blank. I learned Xamarin years ago in college before all the updates and I am having trouble sorting out this issue. I can't seem to find information on how to fix this problem.

```
<SearchBar x:Name="Searchbar" Placeholder="Search" TextChanged="
<ScrollView>
<ListView x:Name="listView">
  <ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <ImageCell Height="50" 
                 Text="{Binding title}"
                 ImageSource="{Binding url}"
                 Tapped="ImageCell_Tapped">
       </ImageCell>
    </DataTemplate>
  </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
</ScrollView>


using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using Android.Graphics;

namespace InvestCloudChallenge
{

public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    string searchText;
    HttpClient myClient = new HttpClient();
    string APIKey = "api-key here";
    string url = "https://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?            
    method=flickr.photos.search" +
                 "&api_key={0}" +
                 "&text={1}" +
                 "&format=json&nojsoncallback=1";
    string photoUrl = "http://farm{0}.staticflikr.com/{1}/{2}_{3}_n.jpg";
    IList<Photo> imageList = new ObservableCollection<Photo>();

    public MainPage()
    {   
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private async void updateList()
    {
        imageList.Clear();
        var completeUrl = string.Format(url,APIKey,searchText);
        var results = await myClient.GetStringAsync(completeUrl);

        PhotoData apidata = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<PhotoData>    
        (results);

        if (apidata.stat == "ok")
        {
           foreach (Photo data in apidata.photos.photo)
           {
                Photo myPhoto = new Photo()
                {
                    title = data.title,
                    url = new Uri(string.Format(photoUrl, data.farm, 
                    data.server, data.id, data.secret)),
                };

                imageList.Add(myPhoto);
            }
            listView.ItemsSource = imageList;
        }
    }

    private void OnTextChanged(object sender,TextChangedEventArgs 
    eventArgs)
    {
        if (Searchbar?.Text != "")
        {
            searchText = Searchbar.Text.ToString();

            updateList();
        }
    }

    public class Photo
    {
        public string id { get; set; }
        public string owner { get; set; }
        public string secret { get; set; }
        public string server { get; set; }
        public int farm { get; set; }
        public string title { get; set; }
        public int ispublic { get; set; }
        public int isfriend { get; set; }
        public int isfamily { get; set; }
        public Uri url { get; set; }
    }

    public class Photos
    {
        public int page { get; set; }
        public int pages { get; set; }
        public int perpage { get; set; }
        public string total { get; set; }
        public List<Photo> photo { get; set; }
    }

    public class PhotoData
    {
        public Photos photos { get; set; }
        public string stat { get; set; }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: have you checked the application output to see if it is displaying any relevant messages?  Have you verified that the urls you're building are valid and work in the device/emulator browser?

Comment: Initially i didn't see anything in the output but I did some digging and found this message repeatedly.                                                                                        
                                                                        [0:] ImageLoaderSourceHandler: Could not retrieve image or image data was invalid: Uri: http://farm8.staticflikr.com/7899/33582703938_1e830f040f_n.jpg                                                                                                    I checked the link in the browser of the device and it pulls up the image correctly.

Comment: that url doesn't load for me.  Is it a private image?  Do you have to set any headers or authentication to retrieve it?

Comment: It doesn't work in my computer browser either it will only load when i try it in the device browser. I am not sure why.

Comment: staticfli**C**kr.com - you left out thee second "C"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Flickr is misspelt in the url

```
string photoUrl = "http://farm{0}.staticflikr.com/{1}/{2}_{3}_n.jpg";
```

should be

```
string photoUrl = "http://farm{0}.staticflickr.com/{1}/{2}_{3}_n.jpg";
```

Comment: *facepalm.... ugh it's always the tiny typo that causes an issue. Thank you so much for your help!